# MYSQL filter table by related options table with grouped records

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

**items:**

```
id   name
4   Item Blue, L
2   Item Blue, S
6   Item Green
8   Item L
9   Item Red, Blue, Green, S, M, L
5   Item Red, L
3   Item Red, M
1   Item Red, S
7   Item S
```

**options:**

```
id   group   name
1   1   red
2   1   blue
3   1   green
4   2   s
5   2   m
6   2   l
```

**items_has_options:**

```
item_id   options_id
1   1
1   4
2   2
2   4
3   1
3   5
4   2
4   6
5   1
5   6
6   3
7   4
8   6
9   1
9   2
9   3
9   4
9   5
9   6
```

How can i select items which have options: **(red or blue or green) and (s)**? I need to choose items which have some options from different groups. Options may have many groups, not only two. Result must be:

```
2   Item Blue, S
9   Item Red, Blue, Green, S, M, L
1   Item Red, S
```

Comment: Can you create a schema on sqlfiddle.com? It will be more easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this will work but it might get you started..

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.name FROM items i
INNER JOIN items_has_options ihs1 ON
    i.id = ihs1.item_id
INNER JOIN items_has_options ihs2 ON
    i.id = ihs2.item_id
INNER JOIN options o1 ON
    ihs1.options = o1.id AND (o1.name = "red" OR o1.name = "blue" OR o1.name="green")
INNER JOIN options o2 ON
    ihs2.options = o2.id AND o2.name = "s"
```

The idea is that you join with the options table twice, once for color and once for size.
You need the distinct since you will get duplicate rows from o1...

Comment: Doesn't work. :( If remove last join returns all green, blue or green. If add last join returns nothing.

Comment: And if you remove the o1 join..?

Comment: Hmm. I think you might have to do the same duplicate join for item_has_options to. So a ihs1 and a ihs2 that will be joined to o1 and o2 respectively..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but, should work

```
SELECT count(iid), i.name FROM items i
INNER JOIN items_has_options ihs ON
    i.id = ihs.item_id
INNER JOIN options oON
    ihs.options = o.id
WHERE i.name ='Item Blue, S'
```